# how to using count() method in xpath with dom4j?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom4j

I want to get the count of node of book:

```
<books>
<book>1</book>
<book>2</book>
<book>3</book>
</books>


Document document = null;
try
{           
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("./src/main/java/live.xml"));
    document = reader.read(in);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Node node = document.selectSingleNode("count(/books/book)");
```

the exception:
`org.dom4j.XPathException`: Exception occurred evaluting XPath: The result of the XPath expression is not a Node. It was: 3.0 of type: java.lang.Double.

My question is if I want to use count method in xpath, how to convert Node type to Double type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Use [numberValueOf()](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/Node.html#numberValueOf%28java.lang.String%29)**

> public [Number](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) numberValueOf([String](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) xpathExpression)
>
> *numberValueOf*
>   evaluates an XPath expression and returns the numeric value of the
>   XPath expression if the XPath expression results in a number, or null
>   if the result is not a number.
>
> **Parameters**: *xpathExpression* - is the XPath expression to be evaluated
>
> **Returns:** the numeric result of the XPath expression or null if the
>   result is not a number.

Example:

```
document.numberValueOf("count(/books/book)");
```